# eMails sent from G-Suite go to Spam in Gmail clients. IP and Domain not blacklisted

Tags: g-suite, gmail, spam-filter, spam-marked

We are running a platform with + 1 Mio users who sign-up with double opt-in to nurture them and allow them to be notified etc. All notifications by email are using our main domain (example.com) that we also use for Mailers with our CRM etc.

On the other hand we have a team of 50 people who use the same domain for their business emails on G-Suite.

We understand that it is very difficult to keep sender reputation clean if you are sending + 1 Mio emails per month but checking common blacklists, spam score etc. we are fine. Nevertheless most of our email end up in the Spam folder in G-Mail (not in many other email clients) and that includes the personal business emails sent from our team members via g-suite even.

The notification that appears on the recipient in the Spam folder says:
**"Why is this message in spam? Lots of messages from example.com were identified as spam in the past."**

Does anyone has an idea how we can resolve that?

there is two issues here:

1. How can we find out the cause for that and fix it in general for all emails sent with this domain (@example.com)
2. Even if our massive users notifications and emails (after double-optin verification) might end up in Spam, we would like to avoid that same happens with our business emails sent from G-suite as they are 1:1 conversations from our team member to providers, clients etc.

Comment: Google is perfectly capable and willing to treat different classes of mailings differently, even originating from the same domain - you just need to make it easy for them to distinguish them. Your first step should be measuring how different classes of email are treated. Have you implemented headers for Feedback loop as recommended in the Google Postmaster docs?

Comment: "nurture" and "notify"? What exactly does this mean? Do people opt in for something and then they receive mail about something else?

Comment: nurture = they opt in for getting 1) internal notification for example when a user interacts with them and 2) marketing emails from us. So they get what they opt in for and in each communication we have a cal to action to opt out.

Comment: Thx, "headers for Feedback loop" not yet. Good point. Any other tip how Google Postmaster can be usefuñl?